# Print RESTAPI list data

Tags: rest

when I provide following info as input how do i print the elements
def pauth_cred(self, authmode, issudoenable, ppasswd, cdname, usernam):
auth_data = {
"AuthMode": authmode,
"IsSudoEnabled": issudoenable,
"Password": ppasswd,
"CredentialName": cdname,
"UserName": usernam
}
input data contains following elements